# Event upcasting in saga

Tags: java, spring-boot, cqrs, axon

I have an event that is serialized using `XStreamSerializer` in a saga like so:

```
public class MyEvent {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    ...
}

public MySaga {
    ....
    private MyEvent myEvent;
    ....
}
```

After creating several sagas with that event I needed to modify the event by adding a property:

```
public class MyEvent {
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private String property2;
    ...
}
```

And now I'm having problem on deserialization.
I have figured out a workaround by using a Serialization id that solves the problem,
but I need to implement some sort of upcasting procedure similar to the event upcasting, but for the sagas, in which I override the deserialization process and upcast the inner property `myEvent` to the new event.
Is this possible?
My guess is that I should override `ConverterFactory` class somehow but I'm not sure how.
Could anybody advice something please?

Comment: Hey, can you also post what you have tried and what you want to achieve? AFAIK, the upcaster chain should also work for Sagas meaning your Saga will get the latest version of the event on its handler.

Answer (score 1):

Based your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69405491/convert-byte-to-xml/69462848#69462848), I assume you are using Axon Framework `v2.4.6`.

As you can find on the docs, Axon provide an example of how to write an upcaster [here](https://legacy-docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/2.4/repositories-and-event-stores.html#event-upcasting) using the correct 2.4 documentation link.

You basically get the `intermediateRepresentation` which is an `org.dom4j.Document` since you are using XStream Serializer. Based on that, you have to use methods given by XStream (copy, get, set, remove, etc) and update your XML which is the payload of a given Event.

You can find some other examples on the new docs or on our [code-samples](https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/tree/master/upcaster) repository.

KR,